# Prevent Heroku from starting a web dyno

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to configure a Heroku app to run a scheduled task once per day. My source tree looks like this:

```
bin/myScript
Procfile
package.json
```

When I deploy the app, I see the following error:

```
2017-01-11T04:31:36.660973+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
```

I believe this is because Heroku tries to spin up a web dyno. I don't have a web dyno, nor do I want one. So I created a `Procfile` with this line:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
```

To prevent heroku from spinning up a web dyno.  That didn't work.  What else can I do to prevent my app from crashing upon deployment?  Does it matter if the scheduled task is going to be run in a separate one-off Dyno anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have the line "heroku ps:scale web=0" in your Procfile. 
Doing so tells heroku to create a process type called "heroku" that attempts to run the following command on any dyno instances instantiated for it: "ps:scale web=0". That would probably generate errors, and at any rate, is not what you intended.

Instead You should run "heroku ps:scale web=0" as a Heroku toolbelt CLI command (or do the equivalent from the Resources tab of the GUI, as you already did).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a fix: in the "Resources" tab of the GUI for the web, there is a list of dynos with on/off sliders next to them. I switched the web dyno slider to off, and now when I deploy there is no crash. Still, it's unclear to me why the Procfile line was insufficient.